# How to transform a fragment in a new activity in android?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this activity, with a list of tokens/options in it. As of right now, i have a button that, using intents, opens a new activity based on the item selected (basically: a text to modify the settings and add extra info).

Now, i would like to make the first activity to show, in the below half of the screen,a preview of the new activity, but with fewer/diferent options and less information.

I know how to do that using fragments, but i don't know how to approach the creation of the new activity.
Is there a way to merge them both, to pass the first fragment to the second activity, or do i need to completely code (and thus, modify) "twice"?

Is there a better aproach that lets me do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

If considered you are inflating options in recycler view in the activity, add a frame layout in the same as a container for a fragment to preview the new activity. Set the visibility to gone for the frame layout and when an option is selected set the fragment and display it. For a nice animation use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`
in the options activity xml at the root view. Hope I helped happy coding :)